# Bitmap is returning null reference object but still image resource is right

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

```
b  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.elon);
```

Im trying to create a photo effects app, the thing when I create bitmap using this and this returns a null pointer exception.

What I have done created one simple activity, that has recycler view(Horizontal) at bottom and a image view in above of recyclerview.

The recycler view has only buttons for each effect that has to change, a button is added. when a click a button from recycler view, a method in main class is called and has to run, my MainActivity.java is:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("NativeImageProcessor");
}
Toolbar tl;
ImageView mainImage;
RecyclerView rec;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
com.zomato.photofilters.imageprocessors.Filter myFilter;
Drawable b;
Bitmap input;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tl = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    tl.setTitle("Image Effects");
    setSupportActionBar(tl);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    mainImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
    mainImage.setMinimumHeight((int) (0.6 * height));
    rec= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec);
    rec.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    list.add("Keep original");
    list.add("Star Lit Filter");
    list.add("Blue Mess Filter");
    list.add("Awe Stuck Vibe Filter");
    list.add("Lime Stutter Filter");
    list.add("Night Whispher Filter");
    HorizontalAdapter ha=new HorizontalAdapter(list);
    rec.setAdapter(ha);
}
public void imageOutput(int filterNum){
    try{
        input = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    switch (filterNum){
        case 0:
            mainImage.setImageBitmap(input);
            break;
        case 1:
            myFilter = SampleFilters.getStarLitFilter();
            mainImage.setImageBitmap(myFilter.processFilter(input));
            break;
        case 2:
            myFilter = SampleFilters.getBlueMessFilter();
            mainImage.setImageBitmap(myFilter.processFilter(input));
            break;
        case 3:
            myFilter = SampleFilters.getAweStruckVibeFilter();
            mainImage.setImageBitmap(myFilter.processFilter(input));
            break;
        case 4:
            myFilter = SampleFilters.getLimeStutterFilter();
            mainImage.setImageBitmap(myFilter.processFilter(input));
            break;
        case 5:
            myFilter = SampleFilters.getNightWhisperFilter();
            mainImage.setImageBitmap(myFilter.processFilter(input));
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Here is my HorizontalAdapter.java class:

```
public class HorizontalAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.myViewHolder> {

ArrayList<String> list;
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
HorizontalAdapter(ArrayList list){
    this.list = list;

}


@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    return new myViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.filterButton.setText(list.get(position));
    holder.filterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("exe","1");
            ma.imageOutput(position);
            Log.i("exe","0");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    Button filterButton;
    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        filterButton = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.filterButton);
    }
}
```

}

Here ImageOutput method is called from horizontal recycler adapter passing position of the button as parameter.
and error i'm getting is in bitmap that is in try catch block, showing error as null object reference and crashing, My error program in monitor is:

```
      E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

  Process: com.example.ag.testphotofilterwithbuttons, PID: 2528

    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
     'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:107)
                                                                                         at com.example.ag.testphotofilterwithbuttons.MainActivity.imageOutput(MainActivity.java:69)
                                                                                         at com.example.ag.testphotofilterwithbuttons.HorizontalAdapter$1.onClick(HorizontalAdapter.java:38)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the complete Java stack trace from your exception.

Comment: ya done!! can you check what mistake im making??

Comment: Please post the code to `HorizontalAdapter`, specifically that `onClick()` method that shows up in the stack trace. The `MainActitvity` that you are using for the `imageOutput()` call was not created properly, as if you had tried creating an instance of `MainActivity` yourself.

Comment: Hey commonsware! Done with including horizontal adapter!!

Answer (score 0):

use instead [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context,%20int))

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.elon);
```

Comment: Sorry bro that didnt work for me. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
```

**NEVER** create an instance of an activity yourself.

Since `MainActivity` is the one that is using `HorizontalAdapter`, add a constructor parameter to `HorizontalAdapter` that takes a `MainActivity`:

```
MainActivity ma;
HorizontalAdapter(MainActivity ma, ArrayList list){
    this.list = list;
    this.ma = ma;
}
```

`MainActivity` can pass in `this`:

```
HorizontalAdapter ha=new HorizontalAdapter(this, list);
rec.setAdapter(ha);
```

Comment: Sorry bro I cannot resolve properly!! can I get the exact code?? I instead creating an instance of MainActivity I passed imageviiew and bitmap to adpter and tried changing the effect of the image still crashes the appliaction.